# Develop a bash script using variables

Tags: shell-script, variable

On every reboot the USB port assignments of an attached scanner are incorrect. My goal is to create a script that runs on reboot eliminating my interaction.

Here's what I do manually to correct the port assignments.

```
    1) lsusb -d 04f9:0272  #the output identifies the correct ports of the scanner       
    2) sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/001/002 #scanner now works
```

The following script creates the variables but chmod fails reporting "no such file or directory".

```
    buss=$(lsusb -d 04f9:0272 |awk '{print $2}')
    devis=$(lsusb -d 04f9:0272 |awk '{print $4}')
    sudo chmod a+w /dev/bus/usb/$buss/$devis
```

The correct values are displayed when I echo $buss or $devis.   I know I will need to do more to automate this process.

Comment: What is output of `ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/002` (per your example)? You may find that the easiest solution is to put the set of users who should have access to the scanner in a particular group such as `scanner`. Then no need for fiddling around with a script.

Comment: crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp 189, 1 Jul 24 18:48 /dev/bus/usb/001/002

Comment: This sounds like you should be reading up on the use of udev vs trying to handle it in multi user mode

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably the specific formatting of the `lsusb` output:

```
% usbid=1d6b:0001
% lsusb -d $usbid | awk '{ print "/dev/bus/usb/" $2 "/" $4 }'
/dev/bus/usb/001/001:
```

Notice the extra colon at the end. Fortunately you can easily remove it, either in awk or in the shell, here's an awk example:

```
% usbid=1d6b:0001
% lsusb -d $usbid | awk '{ a = $4; sub(/:$/, "", a); print "/dev/bus/usb/" $2 "/" a }'
/dev/bus/usb/001/001
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the "%" preceding the first two lines?  Also, If possible would you explain what's happening in this string: "'{ a = $4; sub(/:$/, "", a); print "/dev/bus/usb/" $2 "/" a }'"

Comment: Oh, the `%` is simply a shell prompt sign, indicating that that line is typed; the line without it is the output of the command.

Comment: The fourth column is assigned into the temporary variable a, which is in turn processed with a `sub()` replacement to omit the final colon at the end of the line according the regular expression between the slashes. Finally, the output string is printed, consisting of pre-defined parts, the second column, and the modified fourth column. You can read more about these elements of awk syntax in its `awk(1)` manual page.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like it should work, except that the output of `lsusb` contains a colon after the device number:

```
$ lsusb -d 1d6b:0002
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So the `devis` variable would contain that, and the end result would be that you'd try to access `/dev/bus/usb/001/001:`, with the colon.

You can get rid of the trailing colon with the suffix-deleting expansion, like this:

```
devis=${devis%:}
```

Another way to do that in just the shell (without `awk`) would be to just `read` the output of `lsusb`. This only takes the first line `lsusb` outputs, there might be more if there are more than one device that match.

In shells with process substitution:

```
read x buss x devis x < <(lsusb -d 04f9:0272)
devis=${devis%:}
chmod +w "/dev/bus/usb/$buss/$devis"
```

Or with a pipe:

```
lsusb -d 04f9:0272 | {
   read x buss x devis x
   devis=${devis%:}
   chmod +w "/dev/bus/usb/$buss/$devis"
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out where the trailing colon was coming from and there it was staring at me in the lsusb output. ;-(  Are you able to tell me what to do with the file I call "scan.sh" so that it is always read once the OS is rebooted or must I manually execute it in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you provide the output of `ls -l` for your device:

```
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp 189, 1 Jul 24 18:48 /dev/bus/usb/001/002
```

You can see that the user and group already have read/write access. So if you add your users to the group `lp` none of this script stuff remains necessary.